# Time as a determining value

Tags: .net, vb.net, iis

I have a section of code that is being used to determine if a certain event should happen. The code looks like this.

```
        If (Date.Now.Ticks Mod 100) < 4 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
```

The idea here is that this event should happen 4 time out of 100, or 4%. However, in production, the actually percentages range from 10% to 60%. The application is being hosted on two load balanced Win2k3 servers.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting that behavior is *you're not asking for 4% of the time that you be given a True value*, you're asking that any time the number of Ticks modulo 100 is less than 4.

Given a uniform random number generator, as in [System.Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

```
Dim random As New Random()
Return random.NextDouble() < 0.04
```

With [Random.NextDouble](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextdouble.aspx) you will have an equal probability that any number from 0.0 to 1.0 will be selected. Hence I can ask for True 4% of the time by returning true whenever the random double is less than 0.04.

Comment: Meta comment: please don't put the Dim random As New Random inside the method. Make it a class variable. Provided here for example completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use this :

```
Dim r As New Random(System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond)
Return r.Next(0, 100)
```

Comment: Seeding with Now.Millisecond might do more harm than good. The random object should be created once and reused. It will automatically seed based on the time.

Comment: If I were to rewrite the code now, I would take this appraoch. However, since both approaches work fine under unit testing I don't want to make a change to a production system until I can nail down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the results of DateTime.Now.Ticks. On my box (which is a Vista box - the OS is almost certainly important here) taking samples for 5 seconds and getting all the distinct values, *all* the tick counts ended with "91". The code for this is below.

While it's clearly not *that* bad on your server, the timer granularity will certainly have a significant effect. Using a random number generator would certainly be a better bet. Be aware that you ought to create a single instance of `Random`, or *perhaps* one per thread - and that `Random` isn't threadsafe. You might like to use my [StaticRandom](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil/usage/staticrandom.html) class in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) for simplicity.

Here's the tick testing code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach(long tick in GetTicks().Distinct())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tick);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<long> GetTicks()
    {
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5);
        DateTime now;
        while ((now = DateTime.Now) < end)
        {
            yield return now.Ticks;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon, you could add that his code is not asking for something which occurs 4% of the time. It is asking that when this gets run if the tick count mod 100 is less than four make it true. A small snippet explaining how to get 4% 'true' would be more helpful.

Comment: Looks like you were able to provide such a snippet yourself and earn the acceptance bonus entirely reasonably :)

Comment: Heh, I sat there and said if I took the time to comment on yours, perhaps I should just add it to mine. I liked your benchmarking code for proof though!

Answer (score 1):

First off, the number of ticks returned may be scaled by a constant factor from whatever system timer it's taken from, so that it won't hit every integer, and taking it mod 100 won't give you every number from 0 to 99 with equal probability.

Second, if your code is event-driven, the system will determine when it's activated;  this activation time may tend to be a fixed multiple of ticks.  Also, the run-times between activation and execution of your code will tend to be similar.  So, depending on what else is happening on your computer, the tick number will be semi-predictable.

The upshot is, the tick number is highly system-dependent;  you want to use an actual random number generator to get your random numbers...

Answer (score 0):

4 times out of 100?  So you want "Ticks mod 25 == 0"?  Also, I'm not a VB programmer, but can you not get rid of all that "If -- Else" and just "Return (Date.Now.Ticks mod 25) == 0"?

Comment: The percentage is a user supplied value so I don't want to have to change the MOD part of the equations. And yes, very true, I don't really need the ELSE part here.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of randomness is that you get random results. If your actual percentages run between 10% and 60%, your code may be running correctly, but your sample sizes may just be too small for the probability to converge.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [truly random number generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx) would be much better than relying on a function of time.

Comment: Only if security is a factor. In other cases, pseudo random is random enough.

Comment: Why use pseudo random when truly random is so easy?

Comment: RNGCryptoServiceProvider takes 100 times longer to generate a number.

Comment: I'm sure the time taken is _really_ significant